# Merge website and a blog

Tags: wordpress, web

I have around 400 pages in my website. I also have a Wordpress blog. I would like to integrate the two and make it a single blog.

The existing pages on the website have the URLs like;

www.xyz.com/article1.htm,
www.xyz.com/article2.htm,
www.xyz.com/article3.htm

When I create a blog, I want these links to be redirected to new links on the blog, like:

www.xyz.com/article1.htm should redirect to www.newblog.wordpress.com/2009/09/09/article1.htm

www.xyz.com/article2.htm should redirect to www.newblog.wordpress.com/2009/09/09/article2.htm

www.xyz.com/article3.htm should redirect to www.newblog.wordpress.com/2009/09/09/article3.htm and so on.

How can I do this in the easiest possible way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is create a mod_rewrite rule that would simply cover all the cases of your old articles.

If you name them in a uniform fashion (like you do in the example) Then 1 well written rewrite rule should be able to cover all your old stuff.

[Mod Rewrite tutorial](http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite)

Comment: He asked this question yesterday. It was only 40 pages then. I like your answer better than mine, Olafur, so I'm upvoting your answer.

Comment: Thanks Olafur. The htm pages are not in a uniform fashion like article1, article2 and so on. However the base URL is the same. Will mod_rewrite still be applicable over here? Moreover do I need Apache server, since I only have a bunch of 400 htm pages hosted in a folder on a server. I will have to find out the web server. What are the pre-requisites? Any other way?

Randolph, by mistake I missed out a zero, it was 400.